# Ansible Molecule fails to create the docker instance

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ansible, containers, molecule

I am trying to get Molecule working with Docker on a Centos7 host.

The 'molecule create' command fails to create docker instance, and gives error: '**Unsupported parameters for (community.docker.docker_container) module: ...**.'

- Checking with 'docker ps -a' confirms instance was not created.
- I can confirm starting containers manually with 'docker run' works
  fine.
- It's only the molecule failing to start the container

I am stuck with this, and your help is highly appreciated

Here is the complete error message:

TASK [Create molecule instance(s)] *********************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=centos7)

TASK [Wait for instance(s) creation to complete] *******************************
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for instance(s) creation to complete (300 retries left).
failed: [localhost] (item={'started': 1, 'finished': 0, 'ansible_job_id': '353704502720.15356', 'results_file': '/home/guest/.ansible_async/353704502720.15356', 'changed': True, 'failed': False, 'item': {'image': 'test-runner', 'name': 'centos7', 'pre_build_image': True}, 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}) => {"ansible_job_id": "353704502720.15356", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "attempts": 2, "changed": false, "finished": 1, "item": {"ansible_job_id": "353704502720.15356", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "failed": false, "finished": 0, "item": {"image": "test-runner", "name": "centos7", "pre_build_image": true}, "results_file": "/home/guest/.ansible_async/353704502720.15356", "started": 1}, **"msg": "Unsupported parameters for (community.docker.docker_container) module:** command_handling Supported parameters include: api_version, auto_remove, blkio_weight, ca_cert, cap_drop, capabilities, cgroup_parent, cleanup, client_cert, client_key, command, comparisons, container_default_behavior, cpu_period, cpu_quota, cpu_shares, cpus, cpuset_cpus, cpuset_mems, debug, default_host_ip, detach, device_read_bps, device_read_iops, device_requests, device_write_bps, device_write_iops, devices, dns_opts, dns_search_domains, dns_servers, docker_host, domainname, entrypoint, env, env_file, etc_hosts, exposed_ports, force_kill, groups, healthcheck, hostname, ignore_image, image, init, interactive, ipc_mode, keep_volumes, kernel_memory, kill_signal, labels, links, log_driver, log_options, mac_address, memory, memory_reservation, memory_swap, memory_swappiness, mounts, name, network_mode, networks, networks_cli_compatible, oom_killer, oom_score_adj, output_logs, paused, pid_mode, pids_limit, privileged, published_ports, pull, purge_networks, read_only, recreate, removal_wait_timeout, restart, restart_policy, restart_retries, runtime, security_opts, shm_size, ssl_version, state, stop_signal, stop_timeout, sysctls, timeout, tls, tls_hostname, tmpfs, tty, ulimits, user, userns_mode, uts, validate_certs, volume_driver, volumes, volumes_from, working_dir", "stderr": "/tmp/ansible_community.docker.docker_container_payload_1djctes1/ansible_community.docker.docker_container_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_container.py:1193: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.\n", "stderr_lines": ["/tmp/ansible_community.docker.docker_container_payload_1djctes1/ansible_community.docker.docker_container_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_container.py:1193: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead."]}

> ```
> $ pip list | egrep "mole|docker|ansible"
> ansible              2.10.7
> ansible-base         2.10.17
> ansible-compat       2.2.0
> ansible-core         2.12.0
> docker               6.0.0
> molecule             4.0.1
> molecule-docker      2.0.0
>
> $ docker --version
> Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086
>
> $ ansible --version
> ansible 2.10.17
>   config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
>   configured module search path = ['/home/guest/.ansible/plugins/modules',  '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
>   ansible python module location = /home/guest/mole3/mole3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
>   executable location = /home/guest/mole3/mole3/bin/ansible
>   python version = 3.8.11 (default, Sep  1 2021, 12:33:46) [GCC 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2)]
>
> $ molecule --version
> molecule 4.0.1 using python 3.8
>     ansible:2.10.17
>     delegated:4.0.1 from molecule
>     docker:2.0.0 from molecule_docker requiring collections: community.docker>=3.0.0-a2
>
>
> $ cat molecule/default/molecule.yml
> ---
> dependency:
>   name: galaxy
>   enabled: False
> driver:
>   name: docker
> platforms:
>   - name: centos7
>     image: test-runner
>     pre_build_image: true
> provisioner:
>   name: ansible
> verifier:
>   name: ansible
> ```

Comment: You are running a pretty old version of Ansible with the latest available version of molecule. You probably want to upgrade Ansible and try again.

Comment: Thank you @Zeitounator Upgrading ansible to the latest solved it. Those who cannot upgrade Ansible I found a work around  here [link](https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule-docker/issues/150) and it worked as well.